# What's the quickest way to format a disk?

Tags: command-line, dd, fdisk, block-device, removable-storage

It's for a bash script. Basically, I want to format, or erase a USB (or SD) storage device; with a single command line.

I was going to use `fdisk`, but it seems to require user interaction where I want automation.

So then I decided to try zeroing it out with:
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<target disk>`;
but it only seems to zero 2.0 GB of vacant, or unused disk space.

---

```
root@linux:~# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0
dd: writing to '/dev/mmcblk0': No space left on device
3842249+0 records in
3842249+0 records out
1967230976 bytes (2.0 GB, 1.8 GiB) copied, 2.9054 s, 677 MB/s
```

---

Ideally, I'm talking about re-formatting a removable storage device, and prepping it to be imaged with an `.iso` image file (via `dd`).

Re-formatting won't *always* be required, but it also erases data; and clearing the device of any stored data probably ought to be the default behaviour / standard procedure, for this kind of thing anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "format"? If you simply want all data deleted / zeroed, your `dd` command line should suffice.

Comment: what is your real goal? zeroing? formatting (to what filesystem?) - as per your title? both?

Comment: @crater2150 Actually, the `dd` command didn't seem to work for me. I've added details to the question body.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ideally, I'm talking about re-formatting a removable storage device, and prepping it for `.iso` imaging via `dd`. Re-formatting won't *always* be required, but clearing of any stored data should probably be the default behaviour anyway.

Comment: How large is the device, in GiB?

Comment: @Mioriin I don't have it in front of me right now; but it's labelled @ 4.0 GB, so probably ~3.725 GiB. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `fdisk`, with only one partition, with all blocks used, this will suffice:

```
echo -e "n\np\n1\n\n\nw\n"| 
fdisk /dev/<target disk> && 
mkfs.ext4 /dev/<target disk>
```

Change `mkfs.ext4` to whatever filesystem type you want it to use.

If you just want to delete data, your `dd` command should be fine.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try it. How does the first bit work, exactly?

Comment: Also, the `dd` thing didn't actually work for me. It seems to overwrite `1967230976 bytes (2.0 GB, 1.8 GiB)` only; and also indicates: `No space left on device`. I've added more details to the question body.

Comment: the echo at the beginning simulates entering "n [return] p [return] 1 [return][return][return] w [return]" - these are the keys you would press manually within fdisk to select 
1) new partition
2) primary partition
3) partition 1
4) start on lowest block size
5) end on highest block size (i.e. to use all available space on the disk)
6) write partition table & exit